# JSF 2.0 Form - Retrive input data of GUI in Bean

Tags: jsf

I have one question about the JSF managment form. 
I have a XHTML page that contains input text bulit dynamically in a  tag (the data is gey by a List provided by bean), I have to take all value of input text and pass it to bean. I hope I hope I was clear in my shortly description.

Method Bean :

```
public List<ObjectCustom> getList()
{
    return currentPreferences;
}
```

XHTML Page:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{Bean.getList}" var="item">  
    <div class="input-group" id ="sortable"> 
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="#{item.getValue('label')}"
//Note Value: Return a String
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: Yes I have:     public List<Object> getO()
    {
        return o;
    }

Comment: Where did you learn JSF? Have you ever worked through a basic JSF tutorial/book? The average one says that you're supposed to use `<h:inputText>` instead of `<input type="text">` in case you want to transparently process/convert/validate/update the data in bean without any additional manual effort.